# Numpy tile for complex transformation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose there's an array

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

My goal is to repeat `N = 2` times the elements that are on `axis = 0`, so the desired output is

```
array([[[1., 4.],
    [1., 4.]],

   [[2., 5.],
    [2., 5.]],

   [[3., 6.],
    [3., 6.]]])
```

I've tried `np.ones((2,2))*arr.T[:,:,None]`, but the output differs

```
array([[[1., 1.],
    [4., 4.]],

   [[2., 2.],
    [5., 5.]],

   [[3., 3.],
    [6., 6.]]])
```

Is there an easy way to fix that? In guess it's the matter of transposition, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

**EDIT:** I've found the answer. It is:

```
np.transpose(np.ones((2,2))*arr.T[:,:,None], axes = tuple([0, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: Using `np.tile`: `np.tile(arr.T[:,:,None], (1,1,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although [@chrslg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20037042/chrslg)'s `stride_tricks` solution might be quick, it is not easily readable. Instead, I'd recommend using the numpy [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) function, which makes it clear what you're doing. That said, you cannot use it directly to get the result you want, you'll first need to add another dimension to split the rows. Because of that split, it should be applied to `axis=1` instead of 0. The final result then needs to be transposed to match what you're looking for.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
res = np.repeat(arr[:, None, :], 2, axis=1).T
print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[[[1 4]
  [1 4]]

 [[2 5]
  [2 5]]

 [[3 6]
  [3 6]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

One method

```py
(s0,s1)=arr.strides
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(3, 2, 2), strides=(s1,0,s0))
```

Note that it is basically free: it does nothing, and return the same `arr`. Just, a change of strides make iterations goes along `arr` axis 1 for the new array axis 0; just repeat for axis 1; and along `arr` axis 0 for the new array axis 2.

A generalization to all sizes of 2D `arr`, and all repetitions

```py
def myrepeat(arr, n):
   (sh0,sh1)=arr.shape
   (st0,st1)=arr.strides
   return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(sh1,n,sh0), strides=(st1,0,st0))

# Example
arr=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
myrepeat(arr,3)
```

Returns

```
array([[[ 0,  5, 10, 15],
        [ 0,  5, 10, 15],
        [ 0,  5, 10, 15]],

       [[ 1,  6, 11, 16],
        [ 1,  6, 11, 16],
        [ 1,  6, 11, 16]],

       [[ 2,  7, 12, 17],
        [ 2,  7, 12, 17],
        [ 2,  7, 12, 17]],

       [[ 3,  8, 13, 18],
        [ 3,  8, 13, 18],
        [ 3,  8, 13, 18]],

       [[ 4,  9, 14, 19],
        [ 4,  9, 14, 19],
        [ 4,  9, 14, 19]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and a generalization. Could I ask what do you think about my approach? It also seems to work.

Comment: @thesecond Your method is working also. But, firstly, it is not easily generalizable to other dimensions. Tho, an easy way to make it work for any shape is to use `np.ones((1,2))` instead of `((2,2))`. Or even `np.ones((2,))`. What you are doing here, indeed, is take advantage of broadcasting on the last axis. Since last axis of `arr[:,:,None]` is size 1, and `np.ones` last axis is size 2, it forces to implicitly duplicate (broadcast) single value of last axis of `arr[:,:,None]` before multiplying it my all values of `np.ones` (so, two `1`).

Comment: But that occurs only on that last axis of size 1. For the second last axis, size of neither `arr[:,:,None]` nor `np.ones((2,2))` is, a priori, 1. So, no  broadcasting occurs. And in absence of  broadcasting, the rules is that the sizes must be strictly identical. So, the last 2 of your `np.ones((2,2))` is the one that does the repeating job. The first is doing nothing but forcing you to respect a constraint: this 2 must be the same as the size of second last axis of `arr.T[:,:,None]`, that is the size of last axis of `arr.T`, that is the number of columns of `arr.T` aka number of rows of `arr`

Comment: In other words, `np.ones((2,))` is not only sufficient to do what you are trying to do. But also better, since it doesn't force you to use dimensions for this `np.one` dependent on the dimensions of `arr`. With your current `np.ones((2,2))` you could not work on 4x5 arrays for example. With `np.ones((2,))` it wouldn't matter: whatever the shape of `arr`, it duplicates each values.

Comment: All that being said, your solution is basically the same as `np.repeat` or `np.tile` based solutions. It duplicates elements. And does a transpose somewhere. My solution doesn't. Which is not necessarily better. Depend on the context. My solution is way faster, since it does nothing at all. It just (as `.T` or `transpose` does: it is just another view of the same array) views the array differently. But it does it even for the repeating part. It might be better if you want that new array for a "read-only" computation.

Comment: But if you need a new array, because you want to be able to modify the content of the new array without impacting `arr`, then with my solution, you would need a `.copy()` to create a new copy of the result. And that `copy()` will cost you the exact amount of CPU that my `stride_trick` spared in the first place. So, in that case, you are indeed better of just using repeat or tile or your solution.

Comment: Also, if your array is really a 2x3 array, and you do this once, there isn't really any point into trying to avoid the copy neither. But if you do this a lot of times, and/or with bigger arrays, then it is worth avoiding the copy the 3 solutions (repeat, tile or your `*[1,1]` trick) are doing.

Comment: Last remark: `stride_tricks` seem complicated, but it is really not, and it worth understanding it anyway. Even you you were to never use `stride_tricks` in your life, it is interesting to understand how numpy arrays work: they are a bunch of data in memory, with meta data being the dtype, the shape and the stride. So that `arr[i1,i2,...,ik]` is the `dtype` at address `data + i1*stride1 + i2*stride2 + ... + ik*stridek`.

Comment: When you are using `.T` as you did, that is what you are doing: swapping strides and shape of the same data. So, no copy. Address is still `data`. But `arr.T` have new stride `(nstride1, nstride2) = (stride2, stride1)` and new shape `(nshape1,nshape2)=(shape2,shape1)`. So that `arr.T[i1,i2]` have address `data + i1*nstride1 + i2*nstride2` = `data + i1*stride2 + i2*stride1` = address of `arr[i2,i1]`. `as_strided` is just choosing manually those new strides, instead of using predefined rule as `.T`

Comment: So, what my code does is just 3 things in one: firstly, I inverted the stride order, just as `.T` does. Secondly it add a new axis, just as `[:,:,None]` does. And lastly, it use a stride `0` for the middle axis, so that `narr[i1,i2,i3] = narr[i1,0,i3]` whatever i2 (it is just the shape that limit i2 to 0 or 1. It is that last operation that cannot be done easily without `strides_trick`, without copy (at least not by a method I am aware of).